# Prove the triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I want to porve the triangle inequality:

$x, y \in \mathbb{R} \text { Then } |x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$

I figured out that probably the cases:

1. $x\geq0$ and $y \geq 0$
2. $x<0$ and $y < 0$
3. $x\geq0$ and $y < 0$
4. $x<0$ and $y \geq 0$ <- Here I am not sure...

have to be proven. However, I do not figured out a concrete method. Are my assumptions true?  How to finish the prove with these assumptions. I really appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: If you can do $(3)$, you should be able to do $(4)$ by using $(3)$.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following

> For any $x,a\in\Bbb R$, we have that  $|x|\leq a$ if and only if $-a\leq x\leq a$

Then since we have $-|x|\leq x\leq |x|$ and $-|y|\leq y\leq |y|$ for any pair $x,y$, this gives $$-(|x|+|y|)\leq x+y\leq |x|+|y|$$

which by the claim is equivalent to $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$, which is the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality/Real_Numbers  - real numbers

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~forehand/67_summer2012_files/triangle%20inequality.pdf  - complex numbers

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If both $x,y \geq 0$ or both $x,y \leq 0$ then we just have,

$$|x+y|=|x|+|y|$$

If one is greater than zero and one is less than zero, then it should be obvious that if it does not matter which one I prove it for.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite way to deal with absolute values is to use the definition I <strike>learned from [Edsger W. Dijkstra's writings](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/)</strike> probably learned from either [Wim Feijen](http://www.mathmeth.com/wf/index.shtml) or [Jeremy Weissmann](http://www.mathmeth.com/jaw/main/jaw0xx.shtml), viz. $$|x| = x \:\max\: -x$$ (see [Wim Feijen and Netty van Gasteren's WF228 [PDF]](http://www.mathmeth.com/wf/files/wf2xx/wf228.pdf) for the earliest reference I could find) and then use the nice properties of $\;\max\;$ instead of the less nice properties of $\;|\cdot|\;$.  Here this helps me a lot, since it prevents a proof by cases.

Working from the right of the left of the equation, the proof becomes a straightforward calculation:
\begin{align}
& |x|+|y| \\
= & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the above definition of $\;|\cdot|\;$, twice"} \\
& (x \:\max\: -x) + (y \:\max\: -y) \\
= & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"$\;+\;$ distributes over $\;\max\;$, three times"} \\
& (x + y) \:\max\: (x-y) \:\max\: (-x+y) \:\max\: (-x-y) \\
= & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"reintroduce $\;|\cdot|\;$ using the above definition, twice"} \\
& |x+y| \:\max\: |x-y| \\
\geq & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"basic property of $\;\max\;$"} \\
& |x+y| \\
\end{align}
Note that in the middle steps I have implicitly used the fact that $\;\max\;$ is associative and symmetric.

Comment: hi, can you please share with us out of which work this is from him?

Comment: @saturatedexpo My memory seems to have been failing me, since I can't find any reference to this in EWD's works.  But I _did_ find some references from some of Dijkstra's colleagues.

Comment: thanks, i'll have something to read i guess ;)

Answer (score 2):

If both $x$ and $y$ are $0$  or $x=-y$ then the inequality is clear. Otherwise we note that for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ $x\le|x|$ and similarly $y\le|y|$, which follows from the definition of the absolute value.

This tells us that $x+y\le|x|+|y|$ which implies $\frac{x+y}{|x|+|y|}\le1$ since $|x|+|y|>0$.

Thus, $|x+y|=|\frac{x+y}{|x|+|y|}|(|x|+|y|)=\frac{1}{sgn\bigg(\frac{x+y}{|x|+|y|}\bigg)}\frac{x+y}{|x|+|y|}(|x|+|y|)\le|x|+|y|$.