# Proof for absolute value inequality of three variables: $|x-z| \leq |x-y|+|y-z|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

$|x-z| \leq |x-y|+|y-z|$

We know that both LHS and RHS are non negatives. So, I thought of proving this by comparing the squares of both sides but can't advance beyond that step. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the triangle inequality?

Comment: @T.Bongers:  I suspect the point is to prove the triangle inequality for the reals, so you can't use that.

Comment: In any case, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/457513/11994 is related, which has proofs in various styles.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708431/proving-the-inequality-a-b-leq-a-c-c-b-for-real-a-b-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two of the variables are equal, it is easy.  If they are not, there are six orderings.  Each order gives you a way to resolve the absolute value signs.  You can check them all.

Comment: x, y and z can be any three real numbers.

Comment: @gary: my argument supports this.  What is your point?  One order is $x \lt y \lt z$ Then you want to prove $z-x \le (y-x) + (z-y)$ which is $z-x \le z-x$  There are five more.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$ holds for any real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ (this is [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)), then you can simply plug in $b=x-y$ and $c=y-z$.

You get $a+b=x-z$ and
$$|x-z|\le|x-y|+y-z|.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way, as we are concerned only with distances between points on the real line WLOG we can shift the origin, so set $y=0$, to simplify the inequality. Now easy to check cases or use your squaring argument.

Comment: can this be made everytime we have an inequality? (WLOG)

Comment: @saturatedexpo This can be done every time the inequality depends only on distances between points.