# Prove this statement (inequality): $|x-y| \leq|x-z|+|y-z|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

$x,y,z$ $\in\mathbb  R$ then $|x-y| \leq|x-z|+|y-z|$

Prove this statement.

I thought it was the triangle inequality, but I can't seem to end up with the correct order.

Comment: It *is* the triangle inequality. Try to draw three labeled points $x,y,z$ and lines between them.

Comment: Note that: $|x-y|=|(x-z)+(z-y)|$, now use the triangle inequality and the fact that $|z-y|=|y-z|$.

Comment: See [Proving the inequality $|a-b| \leq |a-c| + |c-b|$ for real $a,b,c$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/708431) or [Proof for absolute value inequality of three variables: $|x-z| \leq |x-y|+|y-z|$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/675977).

Answer (score 2):

By the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) for any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$|x-y| = |x-z+z-y|= |(x-z)+(z-y)| \leq |x-z|+|z-y|=|x-z|+|y-z|$$

Comment: wow I was just not thinking. Thank you.