# Proving the inequality $|a-b| \leq |a-c| + |c-b|$ for real $a,b,c$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

> Let $a,b,c$ real numbers. Prove the inequality $|a-b| \leq |a-c| + |c-b|$. Prove that equality holds if and only if $a \leq c \leq b$ or $b \leq c \leq a$.

I've tried starting with just $a \leq c$ and using field properties to reconstruct the inequality, however I haven't been able to make it work. I also tried making the negatives positive and stripping the inequalities and making something happen but again I don't know if that's a proper rule and it didn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: $c-c=0{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Similar questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675977/proof-for-absolute-value-inequality-of-three-variables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the triangle inequality and the fact that you can write $|a-b|=|(a-c)+(c-b)|$.

Comment: ahhh I see thanks.

Comment: Ok, I still don't have it solved I think i'm more confused now then I was before.

Comment: Put $x=a-c$ and $y=c-b$. Now apply $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you should prove this by using the triangle inequality. I also think you should try to understand the problem intuitively so I drew a picture:[image]

$|a-b|$ represents the distance between the points $a$ and $b$ on the number line. If $c$ is between $a$ and $b$, or is equal to either $a$ or $b$, then the distance from $a$ to $c$, which is $|a-c|$, plus the distance from $c$ to $b$, which is $|c-b|$, will equal the total distance from $a$ to $b$. In other words, the length of the two red line segments in case $2$ equals the length of the green line segment in case $1$. If $c$ does not lie between $a$ and $b$, as in case $3$, then the distance from $c$ to either $a$ or $b$ must be greater than the distance from $a$ to $b$.

Note that the above is in not a proof but it can help you understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you , I really appreciate you taking the time to draw a picture. I do understand much better now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here is a proof that does not use the triangle equality, and instead uses the definition
$$
|x| \;=\; x\text{ max }-x
$$
together with the properties of $\;\text{max}\;$:
\begin{align}
& |a-c| \;+\; |c-b| \\
= & \qquad \text{"the above definition of $\;|\quad|\;$, twice"} \\
& ((a-c)\text{ max }(c-a)) \;+\; ((c-b)\text{ max }(b-c)) \\
= & \qquad \text{"$\;+\;$ distributes over $\;\text{max}\;$, three times"} \\
& (a-c+c-b)\text{ max }(a-c+b-c)\text{ max }(c-a+c-b)\text{ max }(c-a+b-c) \\
= & \qquad \text{"arithmetic: simplify"} \\
& (a-b)\text{ max }(a+b-2c)\text{ max }(2c-a-b)\text{ max }(b-a) \\
\ge & \qquad \text{"basic property of $\;\text{max}\;$: $\;x\text{ max }y \ge x\;$} \\
& \qquad \phantom{\text{"}}\text{-- to get rid of the parts that contain $\;c\;$"} \\
& (a-b)\text{ max }(b-a) \\
= & \qquad \text{"the above definition of $\;|\quad|\;$"} \\
& |a - b| \\
\end{align}

Comment: Basically this is a variation on this (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/457759/11994) proof of the triangle equality.

Comment: Nice job , pretty clever

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is a simple application of the triangle inequality as already mentioned (with $x=a-c$ and $y=c-b$).

The equality therefore holds when $xy=(a-c)(c-b)\geq 0$, so either when $a-c\leq 0$ and $c-b\leq 0$ or when $a-c\geq 0$ and $c-b\geq 0$, which eventually means when $a\leq c\leq b$ or $b\leq c\leq a$.