# Proof of an inequality with the triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, triangles, absolute-value

How can I prove this inequality using the triangle inequality?

$|a-b| \leq |a-c| + |c-b|$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving the inequality $|a-b| \leq |a-c| + |c-b|$ for real $a,b,c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708431/proving-the-inequality-a-b-leq-a-c-c-b-for-real-a-b-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|a-b|=|(a-c)+(c-b)|\leq |a-c|+|c-b|$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\vert (a-c)+(c-b) \vert = \vert a-b \vert \leq \vert a-c \vert + \vert c-b \vert$$